# Proving convergence of a two related sequences, specifically that one converges to a value half of the other

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose a sequence $a_n$ converges to some $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $b_n$ be defined by $b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}(a_1 + 2a_2 + ... +na_n)$. 
Prove that $b_n$ converges to $\frac{x}{2}$.

I am confused by the above prompt in my textbook, I have looked at some proofs and I see how to get that $c_n = \frac{1}{n}(a_1 + a_2 + ... +a_n) = x$, but I am struggling to see how to expand that given the coefficients in $b_n$.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it monotone or?

Comment: Have you tried sth like: $$\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i\lt \frac{(n+1)nx}{2}\;\;\underline{\lor}\;\;\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i\gt \frac{(n+1)nx}{2}$$

Comment: Then, if monotone (I'm not sure if it holds in general):
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i}{n^2}\lt \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{x}{2}\;\;\underline{\lor}\;\;\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i}{n^2}\gt \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{x}{2}$$

Comment: Well, if it converges, then so must $\left\{a_n^{\prime}\right\}=\left|a_n\right|$... Anyway, I'm not sure, so I won't post anything as an answer until I think about it.

Comment: I forgot to write $\leqslant$ and $\geqslant$ because the equality could hold for a constant sequence.

Comment: The question does not specify if it is monotonic!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=x+d_n$, then eventually $|d_n|\lt\epsilon$.
$$b_n-\frac1{n^2}\frac{n^2+n}2x = \frac1{n^2}(d_1+\ldots+nd_n)$$
Now divide the sum into a finite first part $k\lt N$ where $d_k$ may be large, and the rest where all the $d_k$ have absolute value below $\epsilon$.

Comment: I'm confused on how to use the equation you've given, as I don't see it was found from $b_n - \frac{x}{2}$, which I thought was what I needed to show was less than $\epsilon$

Comment: I subtracted $\frac1{n^2}(x+2x+\ldots+nx)$ from both sides

Comment: Sorry -- still not fully understanding the logic behind it. I'll ask some more clarifying questions then. So you have $b_n - \frac{x}{2} = \frac{1}{n^2}(a_1 +... +na+n)$ and then you subtract $b_n$ from both sides? I'm still very confused as to what you are subtracting from... or what $\frac{(n^2+n)x}{n^2} is...

Comment: @Lollie: If $a_i=x+d_i$, then $$\sum_{i=1}^nia_i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\cdot x+\sum_{i=1}^n id_i$$ You can' t skip elementary things like $$1+2+\ldots+(n-1)+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: @Lollie, although I haven' t answered the question, I think you might have understood sth if you read any of my comments.

Comment: I don't understand why it shouldn't be less? A sequence can be decreasing.